# Complicated MySQL foreign key requirement to two tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship, multiple-tables

I've got over 25 years experience with various DBMS platforms, mostly Oracle, SqlServer, and Sybase, but also some with MySQL (and others). I am trying to do something now with MySQL that I've never needed to do before, and I suspect it is not possible (in any DBMS), but maybe somebody has an idea.

I am building a database from the CLDR globalize/localize data, and I have two tables that define all the locales my app will support.

```
TABLE supported_language:
   COLUMN language_code VARCHAR(4) (PK)

TABLE supported_territory:
    COLUMN language_code VARCHAR(4) (PK, FK to supported_language.language_code)
    COLUMN territory VARCHAR(10) (PK)
```

CLDR locales may be just a language or a language-territory combo, so to get a full list of all supported locales I must either outer join the two tables or do a union. Now what I need to do is constrain various other tables so they reference only valid supported locales, i.e. a language and territory or just a language, as defined by `supported_language` and `supported_territory`. Normally I would do this with a simple foreign key, but since there is no single table that lists all language/territory and just language locales I am at a loss how to do this.

How can I ensure that these other tables only reference valid supported language/territory combos?

Answer (score 1):

How about simply creating that other table that would contain only valid supported locales and using constraints on it? At times, adding redundant (i.e. calculated) data in the DBMS isn't a bad idea altogether.

Sorry if this answer seems too simplistic but sometimes complex problems have a simple workaround.